# Why does iftop show 'b' characters instead of lines?

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, iftop

I am connecting to my Raspberry Pi 4 over SSH. Although I see **iftop** on all captures as having a nice frame, mine shows '**b**' characters instead of lines. The curious thing is, the corner pieces and all other output is shown nicely. Is this something to do with my SSH client built into OS X? Is it a bug in **iftop**?

Screen capture of iftop process over SSH

[image: Screen capture of iftop process over SSH]

Comment: What _terminal app_ are you using on OS X? And do you have the same problem with locally running `printf '\33(0mqwqvqk\33(B\n'`?

Comment: I am using the default Terminal app, version 2.8.3. This prints correctly both on the host machine (OS X) and over a remote ssh (OpenSSH 7.8p1) session to my Pi. It prints similar fork lines to those on iftop.

Comment: Do you use tmux, Screen, or Mosh as part of the connection? SSH is normally transparent to the data, but these programs aren't. (Alternatively, if you aren't using them, _do_ try to use e.g. tmux and see if it hides the problem?)

Comment: Veeery interesting.. I already have screen on my Pi, so I ran it through **screen**, and all the lines display as they should (it does hide the problem). I wonder why this is so... Thanks for the input! (can't upvote your comments, not enough rep yet)

Comment: See https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/775 for more about the underlying issue and a possible solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the env variable `TERM` ( `echo $TERM` ). tmux and friends set it to 'screen' or something similar which might be unknown to the ncurses library. This runtime library is used by iftop to draw decorations and ascii windows.

Set it to something `iftop` accepts and call up `iftop`:

```
TERM=xterm iftop
```

You can set an environment variable in the commandline like above and it will only be used for this invocation of 'iftop'. That's an easy way to test.

If you're on OSX you might use `xterm-256color`, same for linux with `xcfe-terminal` running. I'm using good ol' `/usr/bin/xterm`, so `TERM=xterm` works for me.

To see all possible terminals just use `toe` the "table of (terminfo) entries".

Further man/google keywords: `ncurses`, `terminfo`, `tic`, `ls -l /usr/share/terminfo/?/*`

Comment: Veery interesting... `Using TERM=xterm` does nothing differently for me, but using `TERM=vt100` or `TERM=xterm-color` were the only alternatives I found which completely fixes the issue. This confirms the issue related to this TERM variable. 

It is also interesting to note that this seems to stem from OS X's TERM variable, as both are set to `xterm-256color`, and changing this before opening the SSH connection leads to the target machine adopting this value.

Comment: Even more interesting to note that using iTerm (the open source terminal application) with `TERM=xterm-256color`, the issue does not exist...

Comment: @Dalofeco `TERM=xterm-color` worked for me on macOS Monterey (SSH into Ubuntu).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

None of these suggestions for trying alternate `TERM` types seem to work on Ubuntu 20.x and 21.x either at the text console or via SSH (no X on my server). However, changing `LANG` did the trick:

```
LANG=C iftop
```

Answer (score 1):

iftop uses the VT100 "Special Graphics" alternate character set mode to display these box-drawing characters – it doesn't use plain Unicode symbols. (Technically ncurses manages the screen and all drawing, but iftop seems to be specifically asking for ACS characters, so even if $NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS is active it still doesn't force UTF-8 usage.)

The way it works is that `\e(0` switches to the alternate characters; ordinary ASCII letters like `qwqvqk` are drawn as symbols like `└─┬─┴─┐`, and finally `\e(B` switches back to normal characters.

But I don't know why this problem would affect only *some* graphics, as normally iftop prints the entire line at once – there doesn't seem anything that would force the terminal to switch back to ASCII mid-way through. It might be caused by whatever ncurses and/or iftop version is used on the server.

(When you use tmux/Mosh/Screen, they act as terminal emulators on their own and internally translate ACS to Unicode when receiving data from the program, so Terminal.app receives a "cleaned up" version of what iftop tried to send, smoothing out the impedance mismatch.)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
vim  ~/.bashrc
```

add this line:

```
alias iftop='export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1 && iftop $@'
```

then

```
sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 0):

The last one works on OpenWRT 22.03.3. Nothing else worked. Sorry it's 2023 now. But I had this problem. export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1. I put it in my shell script to run IFTOP.

In OpenWRT, version mentioned above, in SSH session.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]; then
        echo "usage $0 <interface>"
        exit 1
else
        # The below needed, or else lines are letters like qqqqqqqq
        export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1
                iftop -i $1
fi
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).